# get a specific object in arrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How can I get a `List<Student>` data in School list?

```
List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();

School school_aaa = new School();

school_aaa.setName( "aaa" );

Student student_aaa_001 = new Student();
student_aaa_001.setName( "aaa_001" );
student_aaa_001.setAge( 17 );
student_aaa_001.setId( 21345678 );
Student student_aaa_002 = new Student();
student_aaa_002.setName( "aaa_002" );
student_aaa_002.setAge( 13 );
student_aaa_002.setId( 6789876 );

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Students>();
students.add( student_aaa_001 );
students.add( student_aaa_002 );
school_aaa.setStudents( students );

schools.add("aaa");
```

I only have school name.
But it couldn't use indexOf method.
because that's only works same object.

that means I need to get School object not school name.

how do I find School object.

here are DataTypes.

Student.java
[image]

School.java
[image]

Comment: schools.get(i); It will give you scholl object

Comment: thank you for your comment. if you only have school name, how do you know index? it needs index number to use schools.get( index ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to find a specific school in the list of schools. If this is not what you are trying to do, please let me know.

Here's how I would do it:

```
public School findSchool(String schoolName)
{
    // Goes through the List of schools.
    for (School i : schools)
    {
        if (i.getName.equals(schoolname))
        {
            return i;   
        }   
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Java 8's streaming API gives you a pretty neat syntax to doing so, by filtering. If you can assume that there's only one school with a given name, you could use the [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method:

```
School aaaSchool = schools.stream()
                          .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("aaa"))
                          .findFirst()
                          .orElse(null);
```

If you can't, you'll have to do with a sub-list of schools:

```
List<School> aaaSchools = schools.stream()
                                 .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("aaa"))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int cnt = 0; cnt < schools.size; cnt++){
  if(schools.get(cnt).getSchooname.equalIgnorecase("Your school name")){
    // cnt is your index
  }    
}
```